# Propel - Symfony2: propel.path must be defined. DependencyInjection\Exception

Tags: symfony, propel

Running this commad on CLI:

> php app/console propel:build

got

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   The parameter "propel.path" must be defined.

In app/config/config.yml I've already:

```
    propel:
        path:       "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/propel"
        phing_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/phing"
        logging:    %kernel.debug%
        ...
```

I'm following the PropelBundle installation instruction in [Working with Symfony2](http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/working-with-symfony2.html) and installed via composer.

System Info:

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.3.13 
"name": "phing/phing",
            "version": "2.4.12",
"name": "propel/propel-bundle",
            "version": "1.1.x-dev",
"name": "propel/propel1",
            "version": "dev-master",
"name": "sensio/generator-bundle",
            "version": "2.1.x-dev",
"name": "symfony/symfony",
            "version": "2.1.x-dev",

Wamp server Version 2.2

Win7 64
```

Any help will be Very appreciated!

Comment: did you only add the propel and phing paths after trying without because those instructions say specifically NOT to add them if using composer for installation.

Comment: I've tried before and after, with and without. thx

Comment: I'm trying a composer update ...

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct path. Composer usually puts things in a composer dir (or it did last time i worked on it). Have you tried: `%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/composer/PACKAGE` or something similar? Investigate what the actual path is, not what the tutorial says. Another thing yo can do if you want is tell composer where you want it to puts stuff in your `composer.json`.

Comment: composer update went wrong for the same reason...

Comment: thx prodigitalson I'm re-ckeckin this now

Comment: the path seems ok
the bundles reside along the composer dir (as composer is a bundle too) in the vendor dir

Comment: the path SEEM ok ... it depends on how and what SF2 it's expecting to find.
In effect the propel path look strange `propel/propel-bundle/Propel/ProperBundle`.
I've tried to copy the last PropelBundle dir up to the first propel one (propel/ProperBundle/) ... nothin change

Comment: and the problem is propel.path undefined and not path not find ...
who define the path? and who is searchin for the path? and where ? ... a mistery ... I'm deeping down in the kernel code ... help me before I loose my last neurones!

Comment: yes ... i got a stacktrace ... deeping ...

Comment: ... so ...
app/console create a Container with the composer autoload
and then call Propel to execute the command ... but propel throw an exception 'cause require propel.path .
... now ... some propel path are defined in autoload (include_paths.php) but I didn't see any parameter called propel.path till now ...

Comment: finally (and then Ill stop annoyng u for today) ...
Propel/PropelBundle.boot() [line 29] ` require_once $this->container->getParameter('propel.path').'/runtime/lib/Propel.php';` don't find the path to the propel libs.
composer/autoload_real.include_paths.php had already include the propellib for the Container ...

Comment: I think its cache but I cache:clear its broken for the same reason: propel.path not defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solved

The Cache was the problem. Before posting this question I tried to clear it with:

> php app/console cache:clear

But app console wont clear cause his Container is made with the same cache broken parameters. So (two hours and a headache later) **I simply deleted manually all the stuff in app/cache/dev** and now all works fine. Big headache for a silly thing.

Thanx prodigitalson for the help.

Hope this post will help someone.